# Bypass default node executor in Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

I have a project with a default node executor set up with kerberos authentication.

I have a few nodes (not domain joined) defined with the authentication "basic" but it still tries to authenticate through kerberos.

How to bypass kerberos for those nodes?

Answer (score 0):

there was an error in the definition node : winrm-auth-type instead of winrm-authtype. Now it works.

Where can i find all the parameters list for a node definition ?

Comment: If you're using the pywinrm plugin (out of the box with rundeck) take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin#configuration

Comment: If you're using the old winrm plugin (not recommended) take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin#configure-the-plugin